# C++ explicit type is missing('int' assumed)

Tags: c++, class, header, compiler-errors, int

Hi I have an error in my c++ code. I have 2 .cpp files and 1 .h file, Im trying to access 5 strings and 1 int from the header file but I get an error that says "explicit type is missing('int' assumed).

I have some other errors too which are: Missing type specifier, Shops::Items redefinition; different basic types, Overloaded function differs only by return type and declaration is incompatible.

Here are my files:

**UserChoice.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef USERCHOICE_H
#define USERCHOICE_H

class Shops
{
public:

    double Items(string, string, string, string, string, int);

    int main()
    {
        std::cout << newItem1;
    }

private:
    string newItem1;
    string newItem2;
    string newItem3;
    string newItem4;
    string newItem5;
    int newItems;

};
#endif
```

**Items.cpp**

```
#include "UserChoice.h"

Shops::Items(string Item1, string Item2, string Item3, string Item4, string Item5, int     Items)
{
    newItem1 = Item1;
    newItem2 = Item2;
    newItem3 = Item3;
    newItem4 = Item4;
    newItem5 = Item5;
    newItems = Items;
}
```

**Source.cpp**

```
#include "UserChoice.h";
#include <string>

int main()
{
    string Item1;
    string Item2;
    string Item3;
    string Item4;
    string Item5;
    int items;

    std::cout << "What what you like? Chicken, Meat, Fish, Carrot or Apple?\n";
    std::cin >> Item1;
    std::cout << "\nAnything else?\n";
    std::cin >> Item2;
    if(Item2 == "nothing else")
    {

    }
    std::cout << "\nAnything else?\n";
    std::cin >> Item3;
    std::cout << "\nAnything else?\n";
    std::cin >> Item4;
    std::cout << "\nAnything else?\n";
    std::cin >> Item5;
    std::cout << "\nAnything else?\n";
}
```

**Error line**

```
Shops::Items(string Item1, string Item2, string Item3, string Item4, string Item5, int Items)
```

All the code isn't finished yet so I hope you can help me find and fix these errors.
Thanks in advance and if you need anymore info just ask me.

Comment: I believe Daniel's answered your question. A suggestion: instead of having 5 strings in your class and your function signature, why don't you use vector<string>?

Comment: Raja makes a good point. Passing in vector<string> will allow you to have as many items are you like without affected the method signature and you will be able to determine how many items you have by using vector size() removing the need to pass in an items count.

Comment: I get this error on occasion when one of my constructors has a typo in it.

Answer (score 8):

You are missing the return type in the implementation file (cpp) for Shops::Items which would be a double on the basis of what you have your in header file. The other errors you have are very likely related.

It is a little disconcerting having a method named main within your class as it's normally a function name used for your program entry point.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the return type in the definition in `Items.cpp`:

```
double Shops::Items(string Item1, string Item2, string Item3, string Item4, string Item5, int Items)
{
    //...
}
```

You also need to return some value, both for `Shops::Items` and for the class' `main` function.

Regarding the naming: It looks weird to have the "normal" `main` function replicated inside the class and it also looks weird to have a parameter named exactly like the class is named. It does in fact work, but I would flag it in a code review FWIW. :)

Comment: Also, you should not name the last parameter `Items`, as this will certainly clash with your class method `Items(...)` if you try to use the variable.

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke It looks weird, but it is actually allowed and will not necessarily clash, i.e. any potential clash can be resolved by using `struct Items` or `::Items`.

Comment: @DanielFrey Thanks for pointing this out. Maybe I should have said "this will certainly make the code less readable" :)